# Without doing any computations, given two matrix equations, find $det(A)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, matrix-equations

The original question:

> Let $A$ be a $3 \times 3$ matrix with
> $$
> A
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 1 \\ 0 \\ 3 
> \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 
> \end{bmatrix}
> \quad\text{and}\quad
> A
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 3 \\ 0 \\ 1 
> \end{bmatrix}
> =
> \begin{bmatrix}
> 2 \\ -1 \\ 0 
> \end{bmatrix}.
> $$
> Without doing any computations, find $\det A$ and justify your answer.

I know that $\det A = 0$, but I have no idea how to *get* to that answer. I don't even know where to start.

I noticed that
$$
A
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 3 
\end{bmatrix}
=
A
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}
$$
but I don't know what to do with that information.

I can reason some things *based* on the fact that $\det A = 0$, but that's not a given fact so I don't think that'd be helpful.

Comment: Well, the kernel can no longer be trivial....

Comment: When does a linear system have more than one solution?

Comment: Suppose that $A$ is invertible and $A\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 3\end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix}3 \\ 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}.$ These two facts directly yield a contradiction: do you see why? Based on this, what can we conclude about $A$?

Comment: Just subtract. You will get a non-zero vector mapped to $0$.

Comment: @StephenDonovan Ah, so since $A$ being invertible leads to a contradiction, and $A$ is invertible if and only if $det A = 0$, then $det A = 0$?

Comment: Almost, I think you just misspoke slightly: the Invertible Matrix Theorem tells us a matrix $A$ is invertible iff $\det(A)$ is *not* $0,$ so in our case since $A$ is not invertible, $\det(A)$ must be $0.$ (the other comments are leading down the route of showing that there's a nonzero vector which $A$ maps to $0,$ after which we can again apply the IMT)

Comment: Ah yes I meant to say that $det A$ is not $0$. Thank you!

Comment: No problem: to be clear, I would still explicitly state why $A$ cannot be invertible based on the given values. That's really at the crux of the whole argument

Comment: Well, I would stop at: "a regular system has a single solution, therefore this one is singular and the determinant is zero". But the other approaches gien here are of course equivalent.

Comment: Just wanted to say good job on having detail, formatting, and the mention of what you tried in your first post on the site, welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
A
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\ 0 \\ 3 
\end{bmatrix}
=
A
\begin{bmatrix}
3 \\ 0 \\ 1 
\end{bmatrix}......(*)
$$
There are $2$ cases exclusively:
Either $A^{-1}$ *exists* or *doesn't.*

Whereas the former case leads you (on pre-multiplication to ( * ) by $A^{-1}$) to an absurd equality of two different vectors; the only possibility that (*)  holds is the later one i.e. non-existence of $A^{-1}$ which implies det $A=0$.